# Optimistic concurrency: always checks RowVersion IS NULL

Tags: asp.net-core, concurrency, entity-framework-core

Using optimistic concurrency updating the database aways fails. Checking the profiler (SQL server) it seems that the generated statement always checks for a NULL

```
WHERE [ID] = @p10 AND [ROWVERSION] IS NULL;
```

while the ROWVERSION is something like 0x000000000000B490. What might be wrong?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Oops it happened to be a new object that was updated, so the ROWVERSION is NULL. Something like:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("stuff")] MyObject obj)
    {
        if (id != obj.Id)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Update(obj);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
            ...
```

So, better assign the correct ROWVERSION before you update

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, byte[] rowVersion, [Bind("stuff")] MyObject obj)
    ...
    _context.Entry(myObj).Property("Rowversion").OriginalValue = rowVersion;
    _context.Update(obj);
    ...
```